# Recharts Stacked Bar Chart does not have correct XAxis Numbering

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm writing a React app and I'm trying to use Recharts to display some information in a stacked bar chart.  I have the following:

```
const {BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ResponsiveContainer} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {name: "TEST", first: 9, next: 1, last: undefined, lastest: 1},
      {name: "RETEST", first: 6, next: 12, last: 12, lastest: 2}
];
const StackedBarChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <ResponsiveContainer height={500} width="100%">
                <BarChart
                    data={data}
                    margin={{
                        top: 20,
                        right: 30,
                        left: 20,
                        bottom: 5,
                    }}
                    layout={'vertical'}
                    stackOffset="expand"
                >
                    <YAxis type="category" dataKey="name" />
                    <XAxis type="number" />
                    <Tooltip contentStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }} labelStyle={{ color: 'white' }} />
                    <Legend />
                    <Bar dataKey="first" stackId="a" fill="#FFFFB0" />
                    <Bar dataKey="next" stackId="a" fill="#FFFF00" />
                    <Bar dataKey="last" stackId="a" fill="#ED4337" />
                    <Bar dataKey="lastest" stackId="a" fill="#90EE90" />
                </BarChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <StackedBarChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This displays how I would like but the X-Axis only goes from 0-1 when it should have a low of 0 and max of 32.  I've reproduced on JSFiddle so it isn't my environment.

I looked into what XAxis thinks is DataMax and it thinks it's 1, so manually setting my max won't work because then the charts don't fill the space.

Answer (score 0):

I think the domain prop is what you want.
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis#domain

Comment: I tried using the domain prop, I can change the axis size but the bars themselves still max at 1.  The domain prop is what I used to check out the DataMax value and found that it is 1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using stackOffset expand causes this behavior.  It normalized the data to 1 and shows fractions.